# ¿Cómo obtener un valor de una lista y almacenarla en una variable con formato unicode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista

Tengo un método en Python 2.7 que me devuelve como respuesta una lista tal cual:

```
[{u'usuario': u''}]
```

Y necesito obtener sólo el valor y guardarlo en una variable unicode. En este caso sería una cadena vacía, pero podría ser `[{u'usuario': u'Pepe'}]`

¿Cómo se haría esto de forma sencilla?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python es un lenguaje de tipado dinámico, por lo que para que una variable sea un de un tipo determinado basta con guardar un valor de este tipo ahí por lo que las siguiente lineas

```
a = [{u'usuario': u'Pepe'}]
b = a[0]['usuario']
```

En a se guardaria la lista, pero en b se guarda un valor unicode, lo que se puede observar al imprimir b

[image: Unicode]

Answer (score 2):

En realidad necesito mas contexto para poder resolver tu pregunta, pero voy a asumir algunas cosas y tu me diras si es lo que estas buscando.

Supongo que tienes una lista de persona, donde cada persona con sus caracteristicas esta representado por un diccionario.

En este ejemplo supongo que tengo en mi lista 3 personas: Javier, Elena y Maria. Cada uno con su nombre y edad.

```
>>>lista_personas = [{u'usuario':u'Javier', 'edad':30}, 
                     {u'usuario':u'Maria', 'edad':20}, 
                     {u'usuario':u'Elena', 'edad':22}]

[{'edad': 30, 'usuario': 'Javier'},
 {'edad': 20, 'usuario': 'Maria'},
 {'edad': 22, 'usuario': 'Elena'}]
```

Si lo que quiero es solo mostrar los nombres de mis usuarios, haría algo como esto:

```
>>>lista_usuarios = [ persona.get('usuario', '') for persona in lista_personas ])
['Javier', 'Maria', 'Elena']
```

Comment: Es una suposición válida, se me ocurrió algo parecido, esperemos a ver que dice Elena

Comment: Lo único que cambiaría es usar `get` en el diccionario asi nos evitamos `KeyError`s: `[persona.get('usuario', '') for persona in lista_personas]`

Comment: Si tienes razón, ya la edito.

Comment: Aunque la respuesta esta muy detallada, y efectivamente tenia una lista similar; en este caso buscaba guardar el valor, es decir , como me ha respondido @JoelIbaceta, y no mostrarlo por pantalla. De todas maneras, gracias por responder, ha sido de gran ayuda ^^